# Set Bash Variable to another causes operand error

Tags: bash

I've looked through several answers on stack overflow relating to setting a bash variable resulting in a "syntax error: operand expected" and tried some suggestions without success. I'm new to bash and Linux in general so I hope someone can help.

Basically my coworker wants me to run the following in terminal:

```
export TOPDIR=/home/user/folder/subfolder
export TOP=$TOPDIR
```

However I get an error on the second line:

```
bash: export: /home/user/folder/subfolder: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/home/user/folder/subfolder")
```

I have tried changing the line to some variations such as

```
export TOP=${TOPDIR}
```

and

```
export TOP="${TOPDIR}"
```

without success.

Any suggestions or help on what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

NOTE: I tried setting `TOP` to the file location directly without success. If I `echo $TOP` I get `0` returned.

```
echo $BASH_VERSION = 4.2.46(2) - release
```

Comment: Add output of `echo $BASH_VERSION` and `type export` to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus type export - export is a shell builtin

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your terminal with the command and error message?

Comment: What does `declare -p TOP` say?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Try running your script with `-x` (e.g. `bash -x myscript.sh`, or add `set -x` somewhere in your file) and post the relevant output here

Comment: @melpomene I'm not sure what you would get from the screenshot that I haven't already provided. I copy pasted the error line and just substituted the folders to generic names. The folder names don't have any special characters or spaces.

Comment: So I think the issue is that the TOP variable is locked somehow. If I change the left -side variable to TOP1 there aren't any issues. I am going to look where TOP is being defined in my instance.

Comment: Really, `declare -p TOP` is the important one. Please?

Comment: sorry I had done that, was looking at something else. declare -p TOP = declare -ix TOP="0"

Comment: gluster bash completion leaks TOP=0 into the environment - see if you have /etc/bash_completion.d/gluster   :  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1425325

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `TOP` has been declared as an integer (using `declare -i TOP` or equivalent).

From [the `declare` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-declare):

> `-i`
>
> The variable is to be treated as an integer; arithmetic evaluation (see [Shell Arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic)) is performed when the variable is assigned a value.

That's why

```
export TOP=$TOPDIR
```

tries to evaluate `/home/user/folder/subfolder` as an arithmetic expression and fails (because it's a syntax error).

Possible ways to proceed:

1. Find out where and why `TOP` was declared as an integer<sup>1</sup> and (if it was not intended) remove it.
2. Use a different variable name.
3. Use `declare +i TOP` to remove the integer attribute from `TOP`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Possible culprit: The gluster bash completion script [declares `TOP` as an integer and leaks it into the global environment](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1425325). There's a [patch that fixes the problem](https://review.gluster.org/#/c/glusterfs/+/20752/3/extras/command-completion/gluster.bash) (or rather moves it; it just renames `TOP` to `GLUSTER_TOP`).

Comment: I do in fact have gluster on my instance. To mitigate the issue, in the .bashrc file I added declare +i -gx TOP and then made my export after it.

Comment: @swhite I recommend switching to lower- or mixed-case variable names for your stuff. There are a bunch of all-caps variables with special meanings (apparently sometimes including `TOP`), and avoiding all-caps names prevents accidental conflicts like this.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I appreciate the comment and will keep that in mind. Unfortunately, this is a work process that many people use so I would not be able to change it easily since it would break/confuse so many others.